# Override var conforming to a protocol with a var conforming to a child of the overridden var protocol

Tags: ios, swift

This is my inheritance structure

**Protocols**

```
protocol BaseProtocol {
}

protocol ChildProtocol: BaseProtocol {
}
```

**Classes**

```
class BaseClass: NSObject {

    var myVar: BaseProtocol!
}

class ChildClass: BaseClass {

    override var myVar: ChildProtocol!
}
```

I'm receiving a compiler error:

```
Property 'myVar' with type 'ChildProtocol!' cannot override a property with type 'BaseProtocol!'
```

What is the best approach to achieve this?

**UPDATE**

I updated the question trying to implement the solution with generics but it does not work :( This is my code (now the real one, without examples)

*Protocols*

```
protocol TPLPileInteractorOutput {
}

protocol TPLAddInteractorOutput: TPLPileInteractorOutput {  

    func errorReceived(error: String)
}
```

*Classes*

```
class TPLPileInteractor<T: TPLPileInteractorOutput>: NSObject, TPLPileInteractorInput {

    var output: T!
}
```

And my children

```
class TPLAddInteractor<T: TPLAddInteractorOutput>: TPLPileInteractor<TPLPileInteractorOutput>, TPLAddInteractorInput {
}
```

Well, inside my `TPLAddInteractor` I can't access `self.output`, it throws a compiler error, for example

```
'TPLPileInteractorOutput' does not have a member named 'errorReceived'
```

Besides that, when I create the instance of `TPLAddInteractor`

```
let addInteractor: TPLAddInteractor<TPLAddInteractorOutput> = TPLAddInteractor()
```

I receive this other error

```
Generic parameter 'T' cannot be bound to non-@objc protocol type 'TPLAddInteractorOutput'
```

Any thoughts?

Comment: [This Might be Helpful](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24094158/overriding-superclass-property-with-different-type-in-swift)

and [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26188903/swift-override-class-variables)

Comment: Thank you @UmangBista but the accepted solution does not work for me, compiler says I cannot make a downcast from type to the other type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you can do that with [protocols](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Protocols.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH25-ID267)

The way i would solve the problem you are having is with the use of [generics](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Generics.html). This means that you essentially have the classes like this (Updated to a working example).

**Protocols**

```
protocol BaseProtocol {
    func didSomething()
}
protocol ChildProtocol: BaseProtocol {
    func didSomethingElse()
}
```

**Classes**

```
class BaseClass<T: BaseProtocol> {
    var myProtocol: T?

    func doCallBack() {
        myProtocol?.didSomething()
    }
}
class ChildClass<T: ChildProtocol> : BaseClass<T> {
    override func doCallBack() {
        super.doCallBack()
        myProtocol?.didSomethingElse()
    }
}
```

**Implementation/Example use**

```
class DoesSomethingClass : ChildProtocol {
    func doSomething() {
        var s = ChildClass<DoesSomethingClass>()
        s.myProtocol = self
        s.doCallBack()
    }

    func didSomething() {
        println("doSomething()")
    }
    func didSomethingElse() {
        println("doSomethingElse()")
    }
}

let foo = DoesSomethingClass()
foo.doSomething()
```

Remember, you need a class which actually implements the protocol, and its THAT class you actually define as the generic type to the BaseClass/ChildClass. Since the code expects the type to be a type which conforms to the protocol.

Comment: Thanks tskulbru but that is not exactly the same, my ChildClass and BaseClass does not conform to the protocol, that are the variables.

Comment: using my answer doesnt make the class conform to the protocol, it makes the class contain a generic type T, which is of type BaseProtocol or derivatives

Comment: Thanks again I'm trying to implement it, I'll let you know

Comment: Hi @tskulbru, I've updated the question, I cannot make this working :(

Comment: @emenegro so, I've updated to a working example. See my updated code. You can paste the code into a playground to test it out. I can see in your updated code that you don't grasp some of the concepts of protocols and generics, hopefully my updated answer will help you.

Answer (score 2):

@tskulbru is correct: it can't be done, and this has nothing to do with your protocols. Consider the example below, which *also* fails…this time with `Cannot override with a stored property 'myVar'`:

```
class Foo {
}

class Goo: Foo {
}

class BaseClass: NSObject {
   var myVar: Foo!
}

class ChildClass: BaseClass {
   override var myVar: Foo!
}
```

To understand why, let's reexamine the [docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Inheritance.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH17-ID196):

> **Overriding Properties**
>
> You can override an inherited instance or class property to provide
>   your own custom getter and setter for that property, or to add
>   property observers to enable the overriding property to observe when
>   the underlying property value changes.

The implication is that if you are going to override a property, you *must* write your own getter/setter, or else you *must* add property observers. Simply replacing one variable type with another is not allowed.

Now for some rampant speculation: why is this the case? Well, consider on the one hand that Swift is *intended* to be optimized for speed. Having to do runtime type checks in order to determine whether your var is in fact a Foo or a Bar slows things down. Then consider that the language designers likely have a preference for composition over inheritance. If both of these are true, it's not surprising that you cannot override a property's type.

All that said, if you needed to get an equivalent behavior, @tskulbru's solution looks quite elegant, assuming you can get it to compile. :)

Comment: Thanks clozach. I will take a look at the docs because I'm starting to learn Swift and I have not dived a lot on generics more than the basis.

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways you can go with your code, depending what you want to achieve with your code (you didn't tell us).

The simple case: you just want to be able to assign an object that confirms to ChildProtocol to myVar.
Solution: don't override myVar. Just use it in ChildClass. You can do this by design of the language Swift. It is one of the basics of object oriented languages.

Second case: you not only want to enable assigning instances of ChildProtocol, you also want to disable to be able to assign instances of BaseProtocol.
If you want to do this, use the Generics solution, provided here in the answers section.

If you are unsure, the simple case is correct for you.

Gerd

Comment: Hi Gerd. I thought the case was clear, I want to override the var in the base with another var conforming to a protocol that conforms to the base's var protocol. If I use the base class I have one behavior, if I use the child, I have both behaviors, and I can use it polymorphically taking into account the base class. I think this is very common and pretty straightforward. I'm trying to achieve the generics solution.