# Swift Unable to Override Variables in Subclass

Tags: swift, inheritance, sprite-kit

I am working on a macOS project in Swift, and I've been having a lot of trouble with overriding variables in a few classes I've made.  In `classTwo` Xcode is presenting the error `Cannot override with a stored property 'texture'` on the line;

```
override var texture: SKTexture?
```

This is a bit of the code I'm using.

```
     public class classOne: SKSpriteNode {

        required public init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
            fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
        }
// Other functions
    }
```

And the second class;

```
    class classTwo: classOne {
        override var texture: SKTexture? // Cannot override with a stored property 'texture'

        required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
            fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
        }
// Some other functions
    }
```

I do plan to actually define a specific texture for `classTwo`, but for now I couldn't even make this work..  Thanks in advance, and I'd appreciate any help on solving this issue!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Swift override instance variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26188903/swift-override-instance-variables)

Comment: Is it even possible? SpriteKit is a framework by Apple, so I'd reckon this kind of overriding wouldn't be possible

Comment: I don't understand what you mean, UIView is also apple class ...

Comment: Why do you need to override texture at all?

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Inheritance.html and search for `super.` include `.` in your search and read through...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

EDIT

@Knight0fDragon was right, a better approach is to use `super.texture`

```
class classTwo: classOne {
    override var texture:SKTexture? {
        get {
            return super.texture
        }
        set {
            super.texture = newValue
        }
    }            
}
```

---

In order to override the property you need to initialise it. In other words, giving it an initial value. If you don't want, here is a workaround:

```
class classTwo: classOne {    
    var _texture:SKTexture
    override public var texture: SKTexture? {
        get {
            return _texture
        }
        set {
            _texture = newValue!
        }
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
    // Some other functions
}
```

Comment: This is not recommended, there may be a case where something in SKSpriteNode may access texture via the stored variable, not the property, thus giving an undesired result

Comment: use super.texture instead

Comment: Thank you @Lawiet, @Knight0fDragon!  I’ll try to implement this code and let you know on how it go goes.

Comment: @Jake3231 why are you even doing this,  this kind of override is pointless

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
override var texture: SKTexture? {
    get {
        return SKTexture()
    }
    set {

    }
}
```

obviously returning something a bit more useful.

Comment: Thanks!  My plan is to use `SKTexture.init(imageNamed: "someImage")` to give the class a specific texture.  How would I do that with the code you provided?

Comment: Have you tried replacing SKTexture with the init you have above. It should work.

Answer (score 1):

In your subclass you need to do this.

```
override var texture:SKTexture? {
    get { 
        return super.texture
    }
    set {
        super.texture = newValue
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

From all my reading,  I do not think overriding is the approach you want,  you want to create a convenience init

```
class classTwo: classOne {
    convenience init()
    {
        let texture = SKTexture(imageNamed:"myImage")
        self.init(texture,.white,texure.size)
    }    

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder:aDecoder)
    }
}
```

Then to use it, you just need to do classTwo()

(Note, this has not been tested, so I may have typos,  the general concept is here though)