# Replace font for every UILabel in the App

Tags: ios, swift, uifont, swift4.2

I'm trying to change the font by make extension for UILabel

```
extension UILabel{
    var defaultFont: UIFont? {
        get { return self.font }
        set {
            let oldFontSize = self.font.pointSize
            let oldFontName = self.font.fontName
            let newFontName  = newValue?.fontName
            self.font = UIFont(name: newFontName!, size: oldFontSize)  
        }
    }
}
```

then call

```
UILabel.appearance().defaultFont = UIFont.init(name: "My Font", size: 5)
```

But always `self.font` is `nil`
**using xcode 10 swift 4.2**

**Edit:**
Now, after changing swift version to Swift3 it works good, then the problem is in Swift4.

**Are there a solution or Alternative way to do that ?**

Answer (score 0):

try this : 
is appDelegate -> didFinishLaunch:

```
UILabel.appearance().font = UIFont("your font name", size: 15)
```

Comment: then you should create two class that extends UiLabel. and use those to set font and size coustom

Answer (score 0):

Standard way of doing is to create your custom `UILabel` class and use this class everywhere you want that default font. e.g,

```
class MyFontLabel: UILabel {

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)

        self.commonInit()
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)

        self.commonInit()
    }

    private func commonInit() {
        self.font = UIFont(name: "My Font", size: self.font.pointSize)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

So while you technically [can't override an instance variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26188903/swift-override-instance-variables), aka overriding UILabel's font variable won't work, you can extend UILabel.

```
public class CustomLabel: UILabel {
    override public var font: UIFont! {
        get { return super.font }
        set {
            super.font = UIFont(name: "Font-Name", size: super.font.pointSize)
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I've found it most helpful to have add a `style(as style: TypographyStyle)` function in an  extension to UILabel, where TypographyStyle is an enum I've defined that contains a bunch of style properties, including font. I also created a convenience init for UILabel that takes a case of TypographyStyle, and calls `style(as:)`, so that the style will be automatically applied when the label is created.

```
extension UILabel {
    convenience init(style: TypographyStyle) {
        self.init()

        self.style(as: style)
    }

    func style(as style: TypographyStyle) {
        self.font = UIFont(name: style.fontName, size: style.fontSize)
    }
}

enum TypographyStyle {
    case body, h1, h2, h3

    var font: UIFont {
        switch self {
        // here you can return different fonts for the different styles if you like
        default:
            return UIFont(name: "AvenirNext", size: 16)
        }
    }
}

// Usage
let label = UILabel(style: .body)
```

Answer (score -2):

Put this on `appDelegate` in `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` method:

```
UILabel.appearance().font = UIFont(name: "your font name", size: UILabel.appearance().font.pointSize)
```